# c# DataGridView bound to DataTable - How to add character to double-only column?

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, datatable

I've got `DataGridView` bound to a `DataTable` with some numeric data and I need two things to ensure are working:

1. Numeric sorting (`doubles`/`ints`) on every column with numbers,
2. Possibility to add some text (like 'x' or '-') instead of numbers in special cases.

Is there a simple way I could add them at the level of DataTable?

I know I can change type of `DataTable`'s columns to `String`, but then I'd need to add much more code just for the sake of sorting columns by already built-in way - and I certainly don't need to change the way glyphs are drawn, etc.

Also, because of amount and way my DGVs are spawned, it won't be as easy as adding one method for every DGV I've got.

**[Edit]**

I write the same set of DataTables to excel files, so drastic changes to the way they work would be problematic and error prone - I'd like to avoid it.

My code for filling dataTables in most occasions looks like this:

```
var row = MyDataTable.GetMyDataTableNewRow();  
row.partName = part.name;  
row.weight = part.weight.ToString();  // it's double  
row.quantity = part.GetParentSet().FindQuantities(part.name).ToString(); // it's int  
row.maxsize = part.CalculateMaxSize().ToString();  
MyDataTable.AddMyDataTableRow(row);
```

Comment: Can you give a little bit of information on the logic behind changing the displayed number to text? Is it based on the numeric value in the column, based on another columns data, or something else?

Comment: So for those special cases how do you expect to sort those numbers? Following regular string comparison for all the elements or simply ignoring any non-numeric character and doing the normal numerical sort?

Comment: @David:  
My code for filling dataTables in most occasions looks like this:  
`var row = MyDataTable.GetMyDataTableNewRow();  
row.partName = part.name;  
row.weight = part.weight.ToString();  // it's double  
row.quantity = part.GetParentSet().FindQuantities(part.name).ToString(); // it's int  
row.maxsize = part.CalculateMaxSize().ToString();  
MyDataTable.AddMyDataTableRow(row);`  
@Icarus: in the "natural" way - numbers in numeric way and chars/strings alphabetically. It won't bother me, if they would be at the top after sorted descendingly.

Comment: So, you have a `DataTable` with a `Double` type column, and you want to store a `String` in it?

Comment: @mrówa: sorry but when you say "add some text like x" do you mean you have a double inside a cell and you want to show the cell as "x" or that you do not have a double inside the cell but a string ?

Comment: The latter - I'd like 'x' or double inside the cell.

Comment: Thanks, buddy! I'll try it tomorrow at work :)

Comment: @mrówa you still don't seem to explain just how you decide when the numeric value should be converted to text. I've given an answer that works if you always have text in the datatable

Comment: @digEmAll: Great thanks! This is something I was looking for :)

Comment: @DavidHall: I've got numerics in database and I change a few "NaN" and exceptions from lower-level accessors to "x" or "-" on given cells. Also I need to keep the strings set at the level of DataSet, as I've got some excel logic, which depends on the same DataSets (without coding it twice). Thanks for help, anyway :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to define you desired behaviour at `DataTable` level, is introducing a custom type holding both a double and a string, and defining an appropriate `TypeConverter` (to correctly show the objects and enable editing in the `DataGridView`).

e.g. :

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(DoubleOrTextConverter))]
public class DoubleOrText : IComparable
{
    public double Value { get; private set; }
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public DoubleOrText(double val, string text)
    {
        this.Value = val;
        this.Text = text;
    }
    public static DoubleOrText FromString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, string str)
    {
        double v;
        if (double.TryParse(str, out v))
            return new DoubleOrText(v, null);
        return new DoubleOrText(0, str);
    }
    public string ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (this.Text != null)
            return this.Text;
        return this.Value.ToString(culture);
    }
    // define your sorting strategy here
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return 1;

        var other = obj as DoubleOrText;
        if (other != null)
            return this.Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a DoubleOrText");
    }
}

public class DoubleOrTextConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            return true;
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
            return DoubleOrText.FromString(culture, value as string);
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            var dValue = (DoubleOrText)value;
            return dValue.ToString(culture);
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Column 1", typeof(DoubleOrText));

dt.Rows.Add(new DoubleOrText(0.0, null));
dt.Rows.Add(new DoubleOrText(1.0, "X"));
dt.Rows.Add(new DoubleOrText(2.3, "-"));
dt.Rows.Add(new DoubleOrText(4.1, null));

this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the `DataGridView` you can apply formatting at the UI level that handles the case where you and to specially change some values in a numeric column without altering the column to text.

This is achieved using the `CellFormatting` and `CellParsing` events of the `DataGridView`.

Say for example you have an int column in your data table and you want to display all instances of 1 as an x and all instances of 3 as a y.

You use the `CellFormatting` event like so:

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "CustomerID")
    {
        if (int.Parse(e.Value.ToString()) == 1)
        {
            e.Value = "x";
        }
        else if (int.Parse(e.Value.ToString()) == 3)
        {
            e.Value = "y";
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach the underlying data table is untouched as are the underlying cell values, so formatting still works as though you had the numbers 1 and 3.

You then will need to do some processing within the `CellParsing` event to convert the strings back. This again is because your underlying table still has a numeric column.

Something like the following simply uses the actual value of the cell in the case where the value being parsed does not convert to an int. You can however, do anything you need in this handler:

```
void dataGridView1_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
{
    int parsedValue = 0;
    if (!int.TryParse(e.Value.ToString(), out parsedValue))
    {
        if (int.TryParse(dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(), out parsedValue))
            e.Value = parsedValue;
        else
            e.Value = 0;

        e.ParsingApplied = true;
    }

}
```